# Access variable value outside scope of object in scala

Tags: scala

am new into scala and have a basic question. How do I access a variable from outside the scope of an object in scala? Need help on this issue.
When I tried to print the value of variable it gave below error:
error: not found: value x

Below is the code block. I need an user i/p and need to access that outside the scope of method in scala. Please help.

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
val x:Int = args(0).toInt
}

println("Input : " + main _)

val a = main(x)

println(a)
```

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: Have added the snippet.

Comment: How exactly are you expecting to execute the `println`s in your snippet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In scala, you cannot access to the variables outside the scope. If you need them in other scope:

- You might define a global variable and access it somewhere else. (not recommended as this is not a best practice in functional languages set aside scala.)
- You might create a function that creates the output you need, and call that function when you need.

In your example, you tried to call `main` with parameter `x`, but it is undefined in that scope. Also, `main` does not return anything (returns `Unit` which is similar to `void` in Java), so your `println` function would not display anything even if you could access to `x`.